# MongoDB: how to find a value from json data?

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I am working with mongodb and would like to find a value from a `json` data.

My `json` data looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5306d69f80b1027ad2653dad"),
  "Tests": [{
    "_id": "52fda07f1e905ec468d93c29",

    "names": "Art Test",
    "script": "regression/purchase-back-forwd"
  }],
  "browser": ["GC"],
  "creationTime": ISODate("2014-02-21T04:31:27.883Z"),

}
```

From this I have to find out `Tests.names`.

I used this but it is not working.

Here Jobs is the table

```
  db.Jobs.find({Tests.names:"Art Test"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes for `Tests.names`:

```
db.Jobs.find({'Tests.names': "Art Test"})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating the name of the field that contains the array, and the name of the field in the subdocument. as [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index).

The only difference is that you are not using a string as the key. Try something like this:

```
db.Jobs.find( { "Tests.names": "Art Test" } )
```

Comment: Not sure who was first. But this is **technically** correct JSON. The mongo shell will of course do either. Just a note for the reader.